# How to replace elements of a matrix with matching elements of another matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I need to write a function that imputes NA in a matrix by corresponding elements of another matrix similar in dimensions.
I thought it could be simpler to consider the matrices as vectors and reconstruct them, but the code does not work anyway. I tried the following:

```
impute <-function(x,y){
    x<-as.vector(x)
    y<-as.vector(y)
    for (i in 1:length(x)){
        if (isTRUE(is.na(x[i])))
        x[i]<-y[i]
    }
}
```

And I tried to run the function for two small matrices in order to track the imputation, the resulting matrix is NULL

```
> M<-impute(A,B)
> M
NULL
```

This was just an alternative to avoid dealing with several indices from the two matrices. A working and efficient code is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you loooking for this?

```
mm1[is.na(mm1)] <- mm2[is.na(mm1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are they exactly the same dimensions?

```
mat <- matrix(1:100, 10, 10)
mat[sample(1:100, 20)] <- NA
mat2 <- matrix(1:100, 10, 10)
inds <- is.na(mat)
mat[inds] <- mat2[inds]
```